# difference of with and without single quote

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have seen people defined Alias name with and without quotes, but I don't understand the different between them. When and why should we use quotes, and when and why don't we use quotes?

```
convert(char(20) , usr_name) 'Name'; 
convert(char(20) , usr_name) "Name"; 
convert(char(20) , usr_name) Name;
```

Comment: You should be safe to use the column names without quotes, as long as they are not reserved words (like table, select,etc.) don't contain spaces or special characters. Using "Table" or [Table] is almost the same afaik, and single quotes should be used for strings, not column names.

Comment: Use `[square brackets]` but only when you need to (e.g. you're using a space in the alias for some reason). Using single or double quotes just makes those look like strings.

Comment: Square brackets [] force sql server to treat it as a sql server object (table, column..) single qoutes can confuse sql server/you between a string and an object name.

Comment: @Alex Thank you for giving a detail definition.

Comment: I would also suggest using the optional AS. It makes it a lot easier to see that it is an alias. If you develop that habit it also helps with the accidental alias when using table hints or other things.

Answer (score 0):

You need a double quote if you want a space in the field name: i.e.

```
convert(char(20) , usr_name) 'Name'; 
convert(char(20) , usr_name) "Employee Name";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is relating to the rules regarding SQL Server [identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx). When an identifier contains a reserved keyword or invalid character, it must be delimited with double quotes (which is only valid when [quoted identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx) are turned on) or square brackets. In all other cases, the delimiters are optional.

The single quotes are an additional delimiter for column aliases. AFAIK, this is the only situation in which they can be used (aside from when you reference the alias in other parts of the query). But don't quote me on that. MSDN is surprisingly lacking in the description of column aliases.

Nonetheless, the column alias provided in your example does not need to be delimited.